# _OSSpinLockLockSlow while deleting

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am facing this issue in my application which is multi-threaded.

Main thread spawns another thread which is doing some memory allocation internally.

```
//Main thread
if(p) {
   Thread th1(TestFunc, 0);
}

//TestFunc in thread.
unsigned long TestFunc (void * param)
{

     //Do some memory allocation.

}
```

It looks like both the thread are waiting for each other.

Callstack for the main thread is:

```
_OSSpinLockLockSlow
GMFree
operator delete (void *)
Thread:: ~Thread ()
Thread:: ~Thread ()
```

For the spawned thread

```
 _OSSpinLockLockSlow
 GMmalloc_zone_malloc_internal
```

This is the sample code of the problem.

It looks like both main thread and spawned thread are waiting for each other.

What is the cause of this _OSSpinLockLockSlow?

Comment: Is this a problem when GuardMalloc (a memory diagnostic) is *disabled*?

Comment: It is independent of this. Even GuardMalloc is enabled, this problem exists.

Comment: you may need to step through the program to find out more. spin locks can be extra problematic on single processor systems -- depends on the scheduler.

Comment: This is not a consistent problem. This occurs sometime when Enter key is pressed too fast. So while stepping, I cannot predict when this problem will occur.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @Jai: Not so far. I have left my company where I was working on this few months back.

Comment: @Jai, I can't help feeling there is an under-the-hood connection with [this recently surfaced issue with XCode 6.3.1/iOS8.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269243/application-sticks-on-osspinlocklockslow/30333203#30333203) - same apparent pattern. main thread and spawned threads waiting for each other on thread deletion.